A Weak Type of Convexity for Smooth Jordan Domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
Suppose that $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a closed Jordan domain with boundary curve $J$ and interior $\text{Int}(D)$.
I'm sure there's already a term for this, but say that $D$ is $n$-star-convex if there is a finite set $x_1,\dots, x_n \in \text{Int}(D)$ such that for all $x \in D$ there is an $x_j$ such that the line segment from $x$ to $x_j$ is contained in $\text{Int}(D)$ (except possibly for the endpoint $x$ if $x \in J$).  If $n=1$ then this is just star-convexity of $D$ with respect to an interior point.
I feel like I'm being incredibly dumb, but for $J$ and $D$ as above:

If $J$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $D$ $n$-star-convex for some $n$?

I tried a few things to come up with a counterexample, because it seems too good to be true.  I tried making a worm that wiggles or spirals infinitely, but this caused singularities.  I also tried an infinite sequence/Cantor set of little pimples or Bessel-like behavior on $J$, but these constructions failed to violate the condition when $J$ is smooth.  Even when $J$ is just assumed to be $\mathcal{C}^1$ I can't get these constructions to work.

If $J$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $D$ $n$-star-convex for some $n$?

The same could be asked in higher dimensions, assuming it's somehow miraculously true in the plane.  If so then it is possible to, with grunt work, generalize deep results about extension of isotopies of hypersurfaces in dimensions $3$ and up (these results are known in extreme generality in the plane by other means).
A priori it's not obvious why we should require the $x_j$ to reside in $\text{Int}(D)$.  Say that $D$ is weakly $n$-star-convex if we relax the condition on the $x_j$ to allow them to reside on $J$, and allow the segments $[x, x_j]$ to intersect $J$ at interior points.  Supposing the above is false, it might still be useful to know:

If $J$ is smooth (or $\mathcal{C}^1$) and $D$ is weakly $n$-star-convex, then is it $m$-star-convex for some $m$?

This is definitely not true in the topological case: Take a pair of sawtooth curves with infinite, shrinking teeth converging to the same point at an angle, like an infinite Christmas tree cookie cutter.  It will only be weakly $1$-star-convex and will not be $m$-star-convex for any $m$.
Further, it's not necessarily true if you ask for $m = n$.  As in the figure below - apologies for the MS paintjob - take a circle and add on two triangular corrugations with smoothed corners and straight side-edges, such that the angles of the triangles force the center of the circle to be the only point from which $D$ could be weakly $1$-star-convex.  Then it's $2$-star-convex but not $1$-star-convex.

This misbehavior with $m \neq n$ is due to the segments $[x, x_j]$ shown in red hitting $J$ at interior points, in this case tangentially along the side edges of the triangular corrugations.  I don't have an example yet where the misbehavior is due solely to having some $x_j \in J$; is there one?

Actually when $n=1$ it's a bit stronger than classic star-convex.  For the application it's nice if $[x, x_j] \subset \text{Int}(D)$, but take the unit disc, at angle $\frac{\pi}{n}$ add a small tube sticking straight out that get narrow much faster than they get short, such that the tubes converge to $0$.  This will force the only center of star-likeness to be the center point of the unit disc.  Then add a fin with an edge perpendicular to $\mathbb{S}^1$.  This domain is star-convex but not $1$-star-convex, nor is it $\mathcal{C}^1$.  "Narrow faster" prevents smoothing this construction.

For $C^1$-smooth curves this result is a good real analysis exercise since (by a compactness argument and the implicit function theorem) it suffices to consider graphs of functions. It probably also works in higher dimensions too.

@MoisheKohan So the idea is to prove it for graphs, then you'll potentially be left with some polygonal piece(s) left over in $\text{Int}(D)$ for which it's true by triangulation?  Do you have a counterexample in mind or a slick proof idea maybe?  Seems messy but I like this simplification a lot, opens up elementary tricks.

No, the idea is that every point in $D$ has a starlike neighborhood in $D$. This is nontrivial only for boundary points. Then use compactness.

@MoisheKohan But does every point have a starlike neighborhood relative to a point $x \in \text{Int}(D)$?  Are you saying it's obvious?  I am really outside my wheelhouse on this.

Ok I have a proof, using your IFT idea plus my 'wrapping around and get left with polygonal pieces' idea. I'll let someone else post an answer and get some points, I think your idea should get them there!  Wow, surprised this is true.

The isotopy extension comment . . . instead of Kirby's smooth/PL isotopies of smooth/PL hypersurfaces (here let's just do spheres $J$, but seems generalizable by gluing), it's possible to construct the isotopies explicitly by proving that the locus of $n$-star-connectedness varies continuously with $J$ and using its geometric structure in the cylinder to make a continuous path selection of the loci.  There is boundary and unboundedness-of-$n$ behavior but they're both uniformly small.  So instead of smooth isotopy we just require slice-$\mathcal{C}^1$.  Interested or leave it to me?

I might write an answer to the current question a bit later. I am leaving you the isotopy part.

Definition. A subset $A$ is locally starlike if for every $a\in A$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ in $A$ and a point $b\in int(U)$ such that $U$ is starlike with respect to $b$. More precisely, for every $p\in U$ the segment $[b,p]$ is contained in $U$ and $[b,p)\subset int(U)$ (the interior is taken in $\mathbb R^n$).
For instance, every open subset in $\mathbb R^n$ is locally starlike.
Let $M$ be a compact $C^1$-smooth (connected) hypersurface in $\mathbb R^n$ and $D\subset \mathbb R^n$ the bounded open subset bounded by $M$.
Theorem. $A:= D\cup M$ is locally starlike.
Proof. It suffices to prove the existence of a starlike neighborhood (in $A$) for $a\in M$. In view of the implicit function theorem, it suffices to consider   the case when $a$ belongs to the graph of a $C^1$-smooth function $f$ defined on an open ball in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. After translating the origin of the coordinate system, we can assume that the origin is in $D$, $a=(0, f(0))$ and the cylinder
$$
C_{r,\epsilon}:=\{(x,t): |x|< r, -\epsilon < t< \epsilon\}
$$
intersects $M$ exactly at the graph of $f: B(0,r)\to \mathbb R$, $B(0,r)\subset \mathbb R^{n-1}$. I claim that (for fixed $\epsilon$) if $r>0$ is sufficiently small, then  $C_{r,\epsilon}\cap A$ is starlike with respect to the origin. Suppose not. Then there exists a pair of sequences $(x_k), (y_k)$ converging to $0$ in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ such that $q_k=(y_k, f(y_k))\in M$ and the line segment  $[0,q_k]$ intersects $M$ at $p_k=(x_k, f(x_k))$. (I am allowing $p_k=q_k$ in the case when    $[0,q_k]$ is tangent to $M$ at $q_k$.) But then, by the mean value theorem, there is a sequence $z_k$ converging to $0$ in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and a line segment $L_k$ through $(z_k, f(z_k))$ of the same slope as  the segment $[0,q_k]$. Clearly, the sequence slopes diverges to infinity as $k\to \infty$ and we obtain a contradiction with the assumption that $f$ is $C^1$-smooth. qed
Thus, we obtain a cover of $A$ by open (in $A$) starlike subsets. By the compactness of $A$, a finite number of these subsets suffices. This is the weak convexity of $A$ that you asked for.
